# Erro com getimagesize no upload de foto

Tags: php, file-upload

Estou tentando montar um sistema que verifica o *mime type* da imagem ao fazer o upload. Porem está dando um erro.

Segue o código:

```
<?php 

$action = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS));

if ((!empty($action)) and ($action == "add")) {
   // Recebe a imagem 
   $imagem = $_FILES["imagem"];

   $size = getimagesize($imagem); 

   switch ($size['mime']) { 
       case "image/gif": 
           echo "Image is a gif"; 
           break; 
       case "image/jpeg": 
           echo "Image is a jpeg"; 
           break; 
       case "image/png": 
           echo "Image is a png"; 
           break; 
       case "image/bmp": 
           echo "Image is a bmp"; 
           break; 
   } 
}

?>

<form name='form' method='post' action='?action=add' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="file" name="imagem">
    <input type="submit" value="ok">
</form>
```

Log do erro:

> Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /Library/WebServer/Documents/teste.php on line 12

O erro ocorre nessa linha:

```
$size = getimagesize($imagem);
```

Modifiquei para

$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];

Mas retorna erro no `getimagesize()`. “Parameter cannot be empty”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse trecho do código original,

```
$imagem = $_FILES["imagem"];
```

Modifique para

```
$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];
```

O exemplo acima é considerando uma imagem apenas.
Para upload de múltiplas imagens necessita de um tratamento diferente.

Caso tenha dúvidas sobre quais são os índices do array, faça um `print_r($_FILES); exit;`. Então poderá ver a estrutura.

Para dar mais consistência no `switch()`

```
 case "image/jpeg": 
       echo "Image is a jpeg"; 
       break;
```

Mude para

```
 case "image/jpeg":
 case "image/pjpeg":
 case "image/jpg":
 case "image/pjpg":
       echo "Image is a jpeg"; 
       break;
```

O motivo é que jpg pode vir com um desses 4 formatos.

Outro ponto que necessita ser mais consistente é verificar se a imagem existe antes de tentar usá-la.

```
if (file_exists($imagem)) {
    $size = getimagesize($imagem); 
} else {
    // dispara um exception, seta um código de erro.. enfim, o que vc preferir
}
```

Há muitos outros detalhes. Apenas mostrei os mais óbvios e simples.

<sub>Os exemplos são meramente didáticos.</sub>

Comment: deu erro `Warning: getimagesize(102.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/teste.php on line 8` a linha 8 é `$imagem = $_FILES['imagem']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: Estranho pois `tmp_name` não retorna o nome original. Retorna o path absoluto do arquivo temporário. O nome é serializado, algo como um formato md5. Tire a dúvida fazendo um breakpoint com `print_r()` conforme comentado na resposta.

Comment: atualizei minha pergunta com o novo código. da uma olhada ai por favor

Comment: Não modifique a questão inteira. Quando for assim apenas adicione mais abaixo da pergunta alguma informação nova. Eu reverti e coloquei a nova informação.  Mas, pela terceira vez, peço que coloque o breakpoint com `print_r()`.   Sem um feedback adequado não posso continuar.

Comment: desculpa minha ignorância,  mas a onde devo colocar o  print_r();?

Comment: olha percebi que eu copiar a imagem para a pasta a onde esta o arquivo php, o erro não ocorre. parece que o sistema so lê a imagem se ela estiver no servidor.

Comment: A imagem está no servidor, senão o copy não seria possível.